# Segfault when creating a std::string with std::to_string()

Tags: c++

In Linux, but not Windows I get a SEGFAULT at the following location. I currently do not know what is wrong with this section. What I want to to is to push a std::string into a std::vector which is later used for generating a log. The entry at the following position just inherits a timestamp and a perf counter.

```
LogEntry lentry = {
  lentry.m_LogTime = get_time_stamp(),
  lentry.m_LogMsg = "txt: " + std::to_string(GetTickCount() - iBegin) // debugger complains here
};
m_Log.push_back(lentry);

/*
inline unsigned long long GetTickCount() {
  using namespace std::chrono;
  return duration_cast<milliseconds>(steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
}

struct LogEntry {
  std::string m_LogTime;
  std::string m_LogMsg;
};
*/
```

GDB

```
(gdb) bt 25
#0  0x00007ffff2f39133 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::swap(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7f631a9 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&) ()
#2  0x00007ffff7cad5eb in xxx::zzz (this=0x7ffffffe44d0, data=..., iSelModel=2) at file.cpp:1110

(gdb) bt full
#0  0x00007ffff2f39133 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::swap(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00007ffff7f631a9 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&) ()
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00007ffff7cad5eb in AbstractPoserEngine::ExportModel (this=0x7ffffffe44d0, data=..., iSelModel=2) at /home/cst/Desktop/PoserGUI/src/engine/AbstractPoserEngine.cpp:1110
        nDim = {259, 439, 667}
        aSkinMat = std::vector of length 1, capacity 1 = {34}
        iBegin = 13520825
        lentry = {m_LogTime = Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/../share/gdb/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 558, in to_string
    return self.val['_M_dataplus']['_M_p'].lazy_string (length = len)
RuntimeError: Cannot access memory at address 0x3dc775
, m_LogMsg = Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/../share/gdb/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 558, in to_string
    return self.val['_M_dataplus']['_M_p'].lazy_string (length = len)
RuntimeError: Cannot access memory at address 0x4247ae140000000f
}
```

Comment: Why not a simple `main()` function with a simple struct and a call to `to_string()` to duplicate the issue?  What, if anything, does `LogEntry` or anything else such as `GetTickCount()` have to do with the issue you're getting?

Comment: What is this strange initialization code? Why are you using assignment expressions as initializers for the same fields of `lentry`? It might be formally valid after all, but still...

Comment: The code crashes because you attempt to *assign* values to class members inside the `{}` initializer. At that moment the fields are not initialized (constructed) at all and any attempt to *assign* to them will result in undefined behavior. Proper operation of non-trivial assignment operator requires fully-constructed operands. Apparently what you wanted to do is this `LogEntry lentry = { get_time_stamp(), "txt: " + std::to_string(GetTickCount() - iBegin) };` Get rid of the assignments.

Comment: @AnT My guess is that it’s an attempt to use C-like designators in initialization (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization), which unfortunately C++ has no equivalent for.

Comment: Why was this question put on hold after I have answered it?

Comment: @Curious Because it didn’t include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), even though in this particular case it included more than enough information to answer.

Comment: @DanielH But what purpose does putting it on hold serve after an answer was given well after it was answered?

Comment: @DanielH Also, whoa, I had no idea C had named initializers

Comment: @Curious I have no clue; I think the site community goes overboard on requiring MCV examples (they are almost always useful, but not always necessary to answer the question) and this is particularly egregious example where the extra ten lines (and four fewer characters) wouldn’t even help in finding the problem.

Comment: I don't think that this put on hold is okay.

Comment: @DanielH you are probably right, doesn't matter much

Comment: @dgrat I think the SO C++ community just has strong guidelines that people want askers to adhere to when asking questions that involve debugging, because a lot of times people try and spend a lot of time going down the wrong paths due to incomplete information.  I feel like that is understandable ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables are uninitialized when using them as arguments to the surrounding constructor.  If you compile with the appropriate warning flags, you should get an error message.   So my guess is that some `std::string` invariants are broken in the assignment and that is what is causing the segmentation fault.

For example

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Test {
public:
    Test() {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
    Test(const Test&) {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
    Test(Test&&) {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
    Test& operator=(int) {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

class Something {
public:
    Something(Test test_in) : test{test_in} {}
    Test test;
};

int main() {
    Something something = Something{
        something.test = 2
    };
}
```

The output for this code is

```
Test& Test::operator=(int)
Test::Test(const Test&)
Test::Test(const Test&)
```

As you can see the assignment operator is invoked first, which goes against the fact that class objects should be initialized before they are assigned to.   You can see this in action here https://wandbox.org/permlink/hnyF9YAf3JtP13vf or http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc7fe50840d57ac8

Further when compiler with all the warning flags, my compiler gives me the following error

```
variable 'something' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization [-Werror,-Wuninitialized]
```

---

Try changing your code to this

```
LogEntry lentry = {
    get_time_stamp(), 
    "txt: " + std::to_string(GetTickCount() - iBegin)
};
```

Comment: @IInspectable they have not, the constructor for the `std::string` objects runs when the constructor for the struct is ran, which happens after the evaluation of the arguments to the constructor

Comment: @IInspectable In the line `lentry.m_LogMsg = "txt: " + std::to_string(GetTickCount() - iBegin)`, the variable `lentry.m_LogMsg` is uninitialized when its `operator=` is called.

Comment: @IInspectable try compiling and running my pasted code and see what happens

Comment: I see my mistake, I completely misinterpreted the expression `LogEntry lentry = { ... }`. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @Curious Can you add the output, and maybe a link like http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73091fe9978ef9da, to the answer? Then it’s clearer that the issue is that `operator=` is called before any `Test` objects are constructed.

Comment: @DanielH good suggestion, ill do both

Comment: (A better link would be http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc7fe50840d57ac8; I switched to Clang because G++ didn’t show the warning message)

Comment: @DanielH added!  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: OMG, I also misread my own code. It is indeed bullshit :/